# iOS - Own URL Scheme and test it

Tags: ios, url-scheme

My goal is test if an App is installed or not in a **non-jailbroken** device.

To start i've tried with two app that i've made myself.

**TestApp** is the app that i want to check, if installed or not.

**CheckApp** is the app that provide the check.

If i've understood, the basic idea around my goal would be to exploit TestApp personal URL Scheme.

So, via Xcode, i've modified TestApp `Info.plist`
[image]

and then i've installed TestApp

Now, in CheckApp i've wrote a simple method

```
func isOpen(_ sender: Any) {

    let appScheme = "testapp://"
        let appUrl = URL(string: appScheme)

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl! as URL)
        {
            print("App is installed")

        } else {
            print("App not installed")
        }

}
```

but if i call it, the console says me

`[17596:13050537] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "testapp://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme installpatch"
App not installed`

I've tested the method with a URL Scheme like `mailto` and it's ok.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: show us the [`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) values in __CheckApp__ as well, please, I'm quite certain that you have just forgot to register the `"testapp"` scheme there.

Comment: Very likely! I'm in the dark about it! Always in `Info.plist`?

Comment: yes, that must be still in `Info.plist` but in the __CheckApp__'s one.

Comment: I cant find it. I've not set and in the Man Page linked there isn't  Xcode name in the column.

Comment: you need to add that manually to your `Info.plist` in the __CheckApp__. it is supposed to be an _Array_ with _String_ elements of the URL schemes you'd like to `-canOpenURL(_:)`; in your case that is `"testapp"` (no quotation marks need to be added, of course).

Comment: Yep! this was the problem! TY! If you provide an answer, i'll mark it as correct one!

Comment: great! :) I'm glad that helped, the answer has been also created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to add the following key to your `Info.plist` file in your **CheckApp** with the list of the URL schemes you'd like to `-canOpenURL(_:)` at the end of the day.

```
LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
```

---

that is how it is supposed to look in general in Xcode:

[image: general list of schemes]

you need to be sure *your* scheme is in this list, like `"testapp"` as per your OP.

---

***NOTE:*** you can read more about that key on [Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html).